# Coding convention for space after pointer *

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, coding-style, conventions

In Cocoa, what's the best convention on writing the * for pointer?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyClass * instance;
```

or

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyClass *instance;
```

I noticed that the auto-generated code for Core Data, puts the *instance by relationship, but * instance by property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * send;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * text;
@property (nonatomic, retain) User *user;
@property (nonatomic, retain) User *userManager;
```

Comment: The answer to that question addresses only the space before the `*`, not the one after.

Comment: Iam especially interested why the CoreData auto generated code makes the space by property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all of the Objective-C code I've already read does it like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyClass *instance
```

Personally, I also think it looks the cleanest/best that way

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use

```
char *examplea;
```

For cases like such:

Say you'd like to include multiple pointer variables in one line like so, you'd need to do so like this:

```
char *examplea, *exampleb;
```

Comment: If you read the question carefully, you'll see OP is asking about the space *after* the *.